# How to find the count of unique terms in a document set?

Tags: python-3.x

Say we have a document set

```
corpus = [
     'this is the first document',
     'this document is the second document',
     'and this is the third one',
     'is this the first document',
]
```

How to find the number of unique terms in each sentence?

I have used

```
count = dict(Counter(word for sentence in document for word in sentence.split()))
```

and the result I got was

```
{'this': 4, 'is': 4, 'the': 4, 'first': 2, 'document': 4, 'second': 1, 'and': 1, 'third': 1, 'one': 1}
```

I'm looking for an output where the key 'document' has a value of 3 instead of 4 because it occurs in 3 out of 4 sentences.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a word to count once for each sentence, you can make a `set` of the words in a sentence before counting:

```
from collections import Counter

corpus = [
     'this is the first document',
     'this document is the second document',
     'and this is the third one',
     'is this the first document',
]


count = dict(Counter(word for sentence in corpus for word in set(sentence.split())))
```

`count` will be:

```
{'first': 2,
 'this': 4,
 'document': 3,
 'the': 4,
 'is': 4,
 'second': 1,
 'third': 1,
 'and': 1,
 'one': 1}
```